# How to compare event.target to a selector

Tags: javascript, dom, delegation

In my function, I am taking a node type, `node`, and attaching an `onclick` to every node in the document on that type.

Then I want to look at the element that was clicked and "bubble up" i.e. add an effect to the node above it that would be selected by `selector`.

The problem is, that the selector my function takes could be a class, a tag, an id, etc...

**So what do I compare `target` to** (in the portion with the surrounding *'s)**?**

```
function myFunc(node, event, selector){

    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(node);

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
         elements[i].onclick = function(event){
            var target = event.target;
             while (target != node){
                 **if (target == selector) **
                        applyEffects(target);
             }
             target = target.parentNode;
        };   
    }

}
```

Also - I am not allowed to use JQuery.
(This is part of a homework assignment, but my question is not directly related to it)

Answer (score 0):

To check whether an `element` (in your case `target`) would have been matched by a `selector`:

```
Array.prototype.indexOf.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector), element) !== -1
```

Comment: That's an overkill way of doing it... But it's more cross-browser than [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.matches)

Comment: @Oriol Wasn't aware of this method, that's why I didn't use it.

Comment: @Oriol actually only Chrome supports it unprefixed